# Origen de "grampa"

Tags: vocabulario, etimología, ortografía, vocabulario-técnico

*Grampa* es un sustantivo náutico que aparece en el *[Diccionario marítimo español](https://archive.org/details/diccionariomarit00madruoft)* de 1831. Ya queda notado que se intercambiaba con *grapa*.

La DRAE indica que *grapa* viene "del cat. *grapa*, y este del franco **krâppa* 'gancho'". No da ningún origen distinto para *grampa*. Quisiera saber cómo y cuándo se añadió esa *m*, si es que la palabra verdaderamente se derivó de *grapa*.

¿Cuáles son la etimología y origen de *grampa*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pesar de que la RAE siempre ha considerado que *grampa* y *grapa* son lo mismo, en otros diccionarios la palabra *grampa* tiene su propia entrada, y al parecer los conceptos difieren ligeramente. La entrada más antigua aparece en el *Diccionario nacional* de Ramón Joaquín Domínguez, de 1853:

> **Grampa**, s.f. Mar. Pedazo de hierro pequeño con punta en un estremo y un ojo en el otro, que sirve para clavarlo en los estremos, y asegurar en él pesos de poca consideración.

En cambio, el mismo diccionario define *grapa* como:

> **Grapa**, s.f. Pieza de metal, con dos estremos que, doblados y aguzados, se clávan o introdúcen en dos cosas que se pretenda unir firmemente.

Como se ve, el término *grapa* es más genérico, mientras que *grampa* es un término marítimo. Además, la *grapa* tiene dos extremos en punta, mientras que la *grampa* tiene un extremo acabado en un ojo. De hecho, en este diccionario es la palabra *grapa* la que se dice que se puede usar también para *grampa* (y no al revés, como el DRAE).

Con el paso del tiempo, ha prevalecido la idea de que son piezas para sujetar cosas, y al final ambos términos han acabado convergiendo.

Comment: Creo que esta respuesta es mejor que la mía. Yo pude encontrar una referencia a que "grampa" era un tipo de "grapa" (un hipónimo), pero no pude encontrar la diferencia entre las dos. Las definiciones que aportas son la clave para distinguir ambos términos! :-)

Comment: @Diego tampoco se me habría ocurrido buscar el dato si tú no hubieras dado previamente la pista de que podría ser un [hipónimo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KU5UAn5). :-)

Answer (score 2):

> Una **grapa, grampa, corchete o ganchito** es una pieza de hierro u otro metal cuyos dos extremos doblados y puntiagudos se clavan para unir y sujetar papeles, tablas u otros materiales.
>
> Fuente: [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapa)

Parece ser que `grampa` viene de "grapa"

> Este vocabulario en su etimología es conferido de “grapa” y con ella del catalán “grapa” y del franco “krappa” que quiere decir gancho.
>
> Fuente: [definiciona.com/grampa](https://definiciona.com/grampa/) (que coincide con la etimología de la entrada de [grapa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JUEahCF) en el DRAE)

En el [wiktionario](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/grapa) encontramos una entrada similar, pero con "grampa" como un *hiponimo* de grapa, lo que quiere decir que una *grampa* sería un tipo de grapa.

A veces las palabras se forman un poco de casualidad como por ejemplo [almóndiga](http://dle.rae.es/?id=20CAqSi) frente a [albóndiga](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1Y2soBd). Es posible que según la región, o por otras circunstancias, se favorezca una palabra frente a otra. LA RAE recogerá ambas versiones mientras se haga uso de ellas (fíjate que en el caso de almóndiga la entrada advierte que ha caído en desuso y que su uso es "vulgar"). No hay una evolución clara de "grapa" a "grampa" (más allá de la obvia similitud fonética) para explicar si es un término surgido de la necesidad de nombrar un tipo distinto de *grapa* (que se ve que no).

Comment: Yo siempre he dicho y escuchado *grampa* (aunque también escucho que al artilugio que sujeta los papeles usando grampas se le dice *engrapadora*). No parece que sea evolución fonética regular, es una simple deformación sugerida quién sabe por qué. Como decir *enjuagar* en vez *enjugar*.