# Se dice humareda, pero en mi vida he escuchado algo que no sea humarea

Tags: pronunciación, dialectos, vulgaridades, fonología, síncopa

Hace unos días descubrí que la palabra `humarea` no existe, si no que el término correcto es `humareda`.

Quedé bastante sorprendido, ya que jamás había escuchado a nadie decir `humareda`, pero sí `humarea`. Imagino que algunos se estarán llevando las manos a la cabeza ahora mismo, mientras que a lo mejor otros están teniendo el momento de "no puede ser, ¿de verdad?" que tuve yo en su momento.

Ahora bien, la pregunta es la siguiente: dado que no aparece en la RAE me gustaría saber si esto ocurre también fuera de Andalucía, es decir, busco usos de la palabra "humarea" si es que los hubiera o un no rotundo a su uso.

Comment: Pues en mi caso es un no rotundo :-) siempre hemos dicho _humareDa_ en Colombia aunque es más coloquial _humero_

Comment: Este es quizá como el caso de "almóndiga", que terminó por incluirse en el diccionario, y me suena haber visto algún post por aquí que decía que de hecho "almóndiga" tenía bastante más sentido etimológicamente. Si luego saco tiempo lo busco y enlazo.

Comment: en Mexico Pronunciamos "humareda" y jamas habia escuhcado "Humarea".

Comment: @Diego I think you meant https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20192/origen-de-grampa/20194#20194

Comment: Tambien en México se dice "humadero"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí este fenómeno (*[síncopa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%ADncopa_(ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstica)) / [elisión](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision#Spanish) / [pronunciación relajada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxed_pronunciation#Spanish)*) ocurre fuera de Andalucía.<sup>1</sup> Se puede encontrar en algunos dialectos de Valencia,<sup>2</sup> las Canarias,<sup>3</sup> y Madrid.<sup>4 5</sup> Y mas allá en los dialectos de Chile,<sup>6</sup> Venezuela,<sup>7</sup> Puerto Rico, Pánama, Perú y algunos 'sociolectos bajos' de Cuba.<sup>5</sup>

Aunque en estos dialectos se pronuncia **humarea*, la ortografía prescrita sigue siendo *humareda*. Del mismo modo con *cansado* (**Toy cansao*), *perdido* (**Me perdío*) etc.

Sin embargo, nótese que sí se usan las siguientes ortografías en el contexto del [flamenco](https://elpais.com/elpais/2013/03/08/opinion/1362773811_160113.html):

- *quejío, cantaor, bailaor, tocaor, granaína, tablao*

o en ciertas palabras relacionada con [la cultura andaluza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andalusian_Spanish#Influence) en general (e.j. *pescaíto frito*, c.f. *sobao*).

---

**Fuentes**

<sup>1. [La elisión de /d/ intervocálica en el español culto de Granada: factores lingüísticos](https://revistas.uca.es/index.php/pragma/article/view/166/169) (2010)</sup>
<sup>2. [Mantenimiento y elisión de la /d/ intervocálica en el español de Valencia](https://minerva.usc.es/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10347/6009/91-124.pdf) (2009)</sup>
<sup>3. [Spanish phonemes and phonetic transcription](http://www.fahs.surrey.ac.uk/languages/spanish-phonetics/advanced-phonetics-7-2/spanish-phonemes.htm)</sup>
<sup>4. [Estudio de la /d/ intervocálica en los corpus PRESEEA](https://scielo.conicyt.cl/scielo.php?pid=S0718-93032016000200012&script=sci_arttext) (2016)</sup>
<sup>5. [Elisión de la /d/ Intervocálica Postónica](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1005) (2000)</sup>
<sup>6. [Lenition, elision and recovery of Chilean Spanish /b, d, g/](http://www.mauriciofigueroa.cl/02_academia/2014_slides_WorkIber.pdf)</sup>
<sup>7. [The elision of / d / intervocalic in the Caracas community](https://scielo.conicyt.cl/scielo.php?pid=S0718-93032016000200006&script=sci_abstract&tlng=en)</sup>

Comment: (More examples at https://raicesdeperaleda.com/diccionario/polvaera/p-5594): "polvaera levantaban los caballos según pasaron. Andaba un airazo que pa qué y con la polvaera qu'había iba yo con los ojines engurruñaos que casi no vía na."

Answer (score 3):

En Chile (donde llegaron muchos andaluces) se acostumbra a eliminar la letra D de la última sílaba, de manera que se dice "ciudá" (ciudad), "humarea" (humareda), "perdío" (perdido), "acabao" (acabado), etc.
En consecuencia, en aquel rincón perdido del mundo se usa y entiende la palabra "humarea".